# Медиазапросы для Bootstrap

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap

Какие медиа-запросы нужно писать в `<link>`, если нужно создать на Bootstrap три версии сайта:

-для мобильного телефона;
-для IPad Portrait версию;
-для IPad Landscape версию.

Comment: верстка на bootstrap подразумевает Responsive (адаптивную верстку). в зависимости от разрешения подключаются нужные медиа стили.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Comment: Получается медиазапросы использовать не нужно ? 
как тогда менять размеры шрифтов при сжатии ?

Comment: Почему не нужно? Вы можете написать обычный медиа запрос с указанием ширины с пикселях. Также Вы можете использовать некоторые уже предопределенные переменные bootsprap. См. здесь: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries Но отдельных переменных для  Portrait и Landscape там нет. Так что я думаю, что Вам остается указать ширину вручную.

Comment: Что это за гаджеты такие, на которые я не могу найти характеристики, найдёшь разрешение экрана в пикселях, напишу как быть с кодом.

Comment: -для мобильного телефона - max-width: 480px;
-для IPad Portrait версию - min-width: 481 px and max-width: 768px;
-для IPad Landscape версию -  min-width: 769px;

Так правильно  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В силу более детального знакомства с Bootstrap3 могу сделать вывод, что почти все сказанное в комментариях к вопросу - верно!